# Unable to run setState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason I'm unable to update the state of my component the first time around. I have a button that triggers the function `uploadInfo()` which checks whether or not the property was changed, and if it was changed set the `previousState` to what it was. Specifically this line: `this.setState({ previousState })` never triggers for some reason.

```
function uploadInfo() {
  this.changeProperty();
  let info = {
    name: 'Red Cup',
    price: 10,
    supply: 500,
    previousState: this.state.previousState,
    counter: this.state.counter, 
  }

  uploadEntry(info)
    .then(res => {
      let hashes = [...this.state.hashes, res]
      this.setState({ hashes, counter: this.state.counter + 1 })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

function changeProperty() {
  if (this.state.counter != 0) {
    let previousState = this.state.hashes[this.state.counter - 1]
    this.setState({ previousState })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating functions in a class, you need to either bind them in the constructor, or use ES6 arrow functions, if you want to access the `this` scope. Try changing your function `changeProperty` to this:

```
changeProperty = () => {
  if (this.state.counter != 0) {
    let previousState = this.state.hashes[this.state.counter - 1]
    this.setState({ previousState })
  }
}
```

[more info on react bind vs arrow functions](https://dev.to/davidleger95/react-quick-tip-use-class-properties-and-arrow-functions-to-avoid-binding-this-tomethods-10j0)

Answer (score 0):

I find binding in the constructor a better approach

```
 class myClass {
    constructor(props) { 
      super(props);   
   }
 this.changeProperty = this.changeProperty.bind(this);
}
```

This way when ever you want to reference the function you can indeed call `this.changeProperty` without a problem

---

Other thing is that I don't know what you were wanted to do here with this callback, but is not doing anything before the `then` you it won run

```
uploadEntry(info) {
    .then(res => {
      let hashes = [...this.state.hashes, res]
      this.setState({ hashes, counter: this.state.counter + 1 })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Hope helps :)

Comment: You're creating the function outside of your class as a regular function. To bind the function, you should do
changeProperty = changeProperty.bind(this)
Right now you're trying to reference a function on the class itself